# Can `patch` be idempotent?

Tags: diff, patch

Can `patch` be invoked with idempotency; i.e., is there some combination of options that will cause repeated invocations of `patch` to have the same effect as a single invocation of `patch` (for a non-empty diff)?

Comment: <mode trolling> Yep! *--dry-run* </mode trolling>

Comment: Upvoted because I love pedantry. :D  Too true, if we extend the idempotency requirement to cover the exit status, this might be the _only_ way of invoking `patch` on a non-empty input! Thank you, @MC68020, for reminding me that a null effect is _always_ idempotent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some patches¹ can be applied multiple times, so this can’t be guaranteed; but

```
patch -N -r- -i your.patch
```

will apply `your.patch`, ignoring any hunks which have already been applied.

`-N` avoids trying to revert an already-applied patch, and `-r-` skips saving failed hunks to `.rej` files.

The equivalent command with long options is

```
patch --forward --reject-file=- --input=your.patch
```

When run this way, if `patch` ignores hunks, it will indicate failure. If the only “error” is ignored hunks, it will exit with code 1 (at least one hunk failed, or there were merge conflicts); more serious errors are indicated by exit code 2.

---

¹ Patches or hunks with no context, or where added lines match the context (*e.g.* a patch adding a polymorphic function where the first couple of lines of the declaration match the next function).

Comment: Related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65698/how-to-make-patch-ignore-already-applied-hunks

Comment: @therealneil [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395363/make-patch-return-0-when-skipping-an-already-applied-patch)